# What would you say to cover anything for the missing part? | "You're not too fat, you're not too short, you're not too .......... you think you are."

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Imagine someone is very critical of themselves, and he/she thinks, **"I am too fat, I am too short, I am too this and too that etc."**, whereas they are not. And you want to boost their confidence and you say just the opposite of what they think they are.

So, I would like to say something like the following sentences, however I can't be sure whether  the last part in bold sounds all right:

1- You're not too fat, you're not too short, you're not **too whatever** you think you are.

2- You're not too fat, you're not too short, you're not **too anything** you think you are.

3- You're not too fat, you're not too short, you're not **too much of anything** you think you are.

Which one of these, if any, would sound idiomatic?

Comment: They are idiomatic in conversation with a friend. Also, you're not too bah blah. Not too yada yada yada.

Comment: In a *conversational* context, you could get away with *"You're not too **fill-in-the-blank** you think you are!"*

Comment: All are OK, but 2 seems the most natural because of lots of phrases along the lines of "You can be anything you want to be". "Anything" is also more emphatic than "whatever": the former suggests that it encompasses everything, while "whatever" is often used to refer specifically to something stupid or easy to dismiss.

Comment: Reality: The person is overweight and shorter than average. What the person *wants* to hear: "You're not too fat, you're not too short, you're perfect as you are.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not too fat, you're not too short, you're not too whatever you think you are. - This is grammatically correct, but "whatever" feels a little vague.

You're not too fat, you're not too short, you're not too anything you think you are. - This is the most idiomatic option.

You're not too fat, you're not too short, you're not too much of anything you think you are. -  "Too much" works grammatically, but IMO, the previous option (anything) is still better.